# job scheduler not working in xiaomi android

Tags: java, android, job-scheduling

**The Job Schedular set as follows**

```
 ComponentName mServiceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TestJobService.class);
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(jobId, mServiceComponent);
    builder.setPeriodic(3 * 60 * 1000); 
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE); 
    builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false); 
    builder.setRequiresCharging(false);
    builder.setPersisted(true);
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) ChaseForceApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

The TestJobService class is like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class TestJobService extends JobService {

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Utility.writeToTheFile(ChaseForceApplication.getAppContext(), "\n\n Job Scheduler StartJob with jobid="+params.getJobId()+" set at " + new Date().toString());

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(this, OnSingleAlarmReceiver.class));
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.i(ChaseForceApplication.TAG, "on stop job: " + params.getJobId());
    Utility.writeToTheFile(this, "on stop job: " + new Date().toString());
    return false;
}

}
```

It's working on most devices, even in other xiaomi phones but in Xiaomi Redmi 3S it is not working.

Is any setting required for Job Schedular to make it work on that device?

Comment: added extra tags, improves layout and wording

Comment: It seems in Xiaomi Mi4i not working too.

Comment: It IS working while the app is in the recent apps list. After swiping it off neither JobService nor AlarmService's (i tried it too) sheduled task exists no more.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Xiaomi MIUI operative system don't allow JobScheduler to run https://web.archive.org/web/20171001070316/http://c.mi.com/thread-8779-1-1.html

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: Updated with wayback machine url

Answer (score 1):

From your app settings/info page, try to enable auto start and then retry with job scheduler. It will work. You need to enable autostart for your app.

Comment: Same issuse. We ennabled  "autostart APP" option of our app and restarted the phone". Sitll not working in (xiaomi miui 10.3.5)

Comment: Same issue: Xiaomi Redmi Note 8T. Battery whitelist and turned off background restriction for app are reseted after reboot, so JobScheduler will not fired.
MIUI 12.0.1 stable...